# Can I prevent an object from being shaded by lights, while still receiving cast shadows?

Tags: eevee-render-engine, shadowcatcher

In Eevee, I'm trying to render an object against a transparent background, while still catching the object's cast shadow.

Unfortunately, the transparent surface I'm using to catch the shadow is for some reason being shaded, and I'm not sure why.

[image]

Is there a way to disable shading except for cast shadows, on a material? Or, alternatively, is there a way I can get the cast shadow intensity in a shader, but not the regular self-shading?